# How to create an AWS Lambda function using terraform which will trigger every 24 hours to check for the files which are names as JWA

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

Here's my code but I'm not able to figure out how do I code my parameter "JWA"

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "every_one_minute" {
  name                = "every-one-minute"
  description         = "Fires every one minutes"
  schedule_expression = "rate(1 minute)"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "check_foo_every_one_minute" {
  rule      = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.every_one_minute.name}"
  target_id = "lambda"
  arn       = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_to_call_check_foo" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name}"
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.every_one_minute.arn}"
}
```

Comment: `my parameter "JWA"` What is that? Your code does not show any such parameter.

Comment: My lambda will trigger and it will choose only the files "JWA". I haven't added it since I'm not sure where to add it or how

Comment: Well now it's one minute, can you not change that? This is documented: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#RateExpressions. You can add your Lambda function code to the original post, there is an Edit option.

Comment: That one minute is fine, I can modify it. The problem is how do I make my lambda raise an event only for certain types of file and not all of them?

Comment: Without the function code, I have no idea. Where are the files stored? If it's in S3, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah in S3, can you please guide me the right way?